# C# Custom response using raw socket

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Custom error message for my firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138472/c-custom-error-message-for-my-firewall)

Hi,

Presently I am doing a project on firewall. Everything is working fine. Here I am filtering all packets going through tcp port. But I need to send a custom page if a page is being blocked. Like "Your Page Is Blocked By Admin". I dont have any idea how to do it. Can I do it using raw socket ? If so please tell me , how to ? Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Thanks.