# C#, custom error message for my firewall

Tags: c#, firewall

Presently I am doing a project on designing and implementing a firewall. Everything is working fine. Here I am filtering all packets going through a TCP port. But I need to send a custom page if a page is being blocked. Like "Your page is blocked by admin". I don't have any idea how to do it. Can I do it using [raw sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket)? If so please tell me, how to? But as I know raw socket does not work for sending on Windows XP SP2 and later, is there any other solution?

EDIT: I used C++ to create a DLL for an IP address filter. Then I imported it in my C++ program. IP addresses are blocking fine. But my customer needs the custom message when a browser is not finding its page.

Comment: Wasn't this exact same question just asked an hour ago?

Comment: Yeah, no answer found then. So I deleted that thread and now asking it again. Because it is very urgent.

Comment: @Barun - please do not do that. If your question goes unanswered you can edit it and provide more detail, and can eventually add a bounty.

Comment: @Barun it is impossible to understand what do you really want. it is impossible to understand the environment. how do you connect? to what? that's why no one could answer.

Comment: "Can I do it using raw socket ?" answer: "Yes"

Comment: @Jon B: Sorry for that. Actually I dont know how to bump my question here. Sorry again.

Comment: @ Andrey: I used C++ to create dll for ip filter. Then I import it in my c++ program. Ip is blocking fine. But my customer needs the custom message when a browser not finding its page.

Comment: -1 for reposting. Baum, if the question is really important, then offer a bounty on it.

Comment: @GendoIkari: well I understand.

Comment: More on the delete-to-repost [on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69851/deleting-your-question-only-to-re-ask-it). (And @Barun, since this [is not a forum](http://stackoverflow.com/about), and answers are not always shown in the order they were posted, the word "thread" is not too appropriate either. And of course all questions are "urgent", but that's [not what these sites are for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6506/an-urgent-tag-for-questions-that-need-answers-within-minutes/6513#6513)... Enjoy!)

Comment: I merged in the answer from the previous post.  @Barun: You can just edit the question to bump it back to the Active queue so it will get more views.  Adding details and what you've tried so far will help people provide better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're selectively allowing access to certain web pages, you're essentially acting like a proxy.  And you'll need to act more like one if you want to respond to clients with an error page.

A browser making an HTTP request will expect the response on the same connection it opened.  In order to return a "blocked" page, you'll need to determine whether the connection is to someplace you don't want the user to go, and if not, return a valid HTTP response (even if that response is an HTTP error like "403 Forbidden" or something more appropriate to a proxy) *on that same connection*.

If you're blocking the connection before it's even opened, ie: blocking access to certain IP addresses, then you're kind of stuck.  The most you could do is return an [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) message saying the host isn't available.  You need to at least accept the connection if you can, accept the incoming request, and reply with your error message.  Anything less, and a browser typically won't know what to do with it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I am not blocking before its opened. All things you just said are true. But the main question is remain unsolved. How can I send Custom Error Page ???

Comment: Implement http and act as a http server/proxy.

Comment: Dont have any idea about it. Can I use C# ?

Comment: Tell me what you want to know from me please ?

Comment: For under 2003 I developed a service with C++ which is a dll. And I importing that one in c#. for uper vista version I used windows filtering platform api which also a c++ dll. and I importing it in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, Since you're working on that low level

Can't you redirect the request by modifying its HTTP header?